# how to working in Accordion control in windows phone 8.1 using c#4.5,XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

My requirement is expandablelistview in windows phone 8.1 using c#4.5 ,xaml blank app for this I am trying to work with accordion control in windows phone 8.1,but there is no accordion control in windows phone 8.1 .Accordion control is work only in windows phone 8.what is alternative for accordion control in windows phone 8.1. How can I proceed to further.Actually I am new to Windows Phone.Anyone help me please.

Comment: Possible duplicate with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474838/how-can-i-make-an-accordion-widget-in-wpf

Comment: Accordion's are easy to make. They're generally just a Toggle button that toggles the visibility of a panel that holds additional content. You can take that concept and build it into the Item Template for something like ItemsControl and voila, you have an Accordion

Comment: Chris please told the answer in detail i am new to windows phone development.